# What goes into sending a FCM from a Firestore to an Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is what I have so far:

1. On Android, user logs in and makes changes to Firestore document.
2. Firestore document gets updated
3. cloud function is triggered
4. cloud function sends message to device(s) using device tokens
5. On Android, FirebaseMessagingService should receive the message but does not.

I suspect the part I am missing is device token registration. Since my server is Firebase and my users login through Firebase, do I need to take additional steps to send the device token to Firebase so that my cloud function can access it? In other words, do I store them in Firestore myself or do they come standard as part of some "users" collection that's controlled by Firebase? For more context, I adapted my cloud function from an example I found online:

CLOUD FUNCTION:

```
exports.coolThingIsHappening = functions.firestore.document("coolstuf/{userId}")
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        console.log("coolThingIsHappening is triggered");
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const after = change.after.data();
        const payload = {
            data: after
        }
        const tokensSnapshot = await admin.database()
            .ref(`/users/${userId}/notificationTokens`).once('value');
        if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
            const logMsg = `user ${userId} has no notification tokens.`
            console.log(logMsg)
            return logMsg;
        }
        console.log("FCM tokens found")
        const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        const tokensToRemove: Promise<void>[] = [];
        console.log(`response results: ${response.results.length}`)
        response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            console.log(`fcm sent: ${result.messageId}`)
            const error = result.error;
            if (error!.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error!.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
            }
        });
        return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
```

*EDIT*

I have proceeded to saving the fcm tokens to Firestore. Any idea how to convert the code above from `database`-centric to `firestore`-centric. I am having some trouble. Android code:

```
val data = mapOf("token" to it)
val collectionName = "users/${uid}/deviceTokens/"
   FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collectionName).document()
  .set(data)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send messages to devices, you will need to write code to collect the device tokens in your app, and store them or send them to your backend.  None of this happens automatically.

Comment: I have proceeded to saving the fcm tokens to Firestore. Any idea how to convert the code above from `database`-centric to `firestore`-centric. I am having some trouble. Android code: `val data = mapOf("token" to it)
                    val collectionName = "users/${uid}/deviceTokens/"
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collectionName).document()
                            .set(data)`

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is about an year since this question has been asked but it may help someone.*

**To send notifications to devices, you should make another collection in your firestore where you store all the tokens from users and then you can get token from there to send notification to anyone.**